# adding .php extension to wordpress urls

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress plugin that adds .php to the end of all pages.

However it does now add the same to posts and custom post types.

The plugin code is below, can anyone help by adapting this?

Thanks

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: .php on PAGES
Plugin URI: http://www.introsites.co.uk/33~php-wordpress-permalink-on-pages-plugin.php
Description: Adds .php to pages.
Author: IntroSites
Version: 1.1
Author URI: http://www.introsites.co.uk/
*/

add_action('init', 'php_page_permalink', -1);
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'active');
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'deactive');


function php_page_permalink() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
 if ( !strpos($wp_rewrite->get_page_permastruct(), '.php')){
        $wp_rewrite->page_structure = $wp_rewrite->page_structure . '.php';
 }
}
add_filter('user_trailingslashit', 'no_page_slash',66,2);
function no_page_slash($string, $type){
   global $wp_rewrite;
    if ($wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() && $wp_rewrite->use_trailing_slashes==true && $type == 'page'){
        return untrailingslashit($string);
  }else{
   return $string;
  }
}

function active() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    if ( !strpos($wp_rewrite->get_page_permastruct(), '.php')){
        $wp_rewrite->page_structure = $wp_rewrite->page_structure . '.php';
 }
  $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}   
    function deactive() {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->page_structure = str_replace(".php","",$wp_rewrite->page_structure);
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }
?>
```

Comment: use `is_page()` to apply only pages

Comment: Hi, sorry I want to apply this to all pages, posts and custom post types.

Comment: to clarify, this code above adds .php to pages only. I need it to add to custom post types also.

Comment: remove $type == 'page' to use with all pages or change in ($type == 'page' || $type == 'your_custom_post_type_slug') to use with pages and your custom post type.